# Can I Inject user request data into model in action filter using MVC style DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.5

I am creating an Action Filter and in OnResultExecuted I would like to check the request for a complex object which I have a set of models to represent the data. I prefer to not manually parse the request and instead use something similar to the controllers Dependency Injection which automatically pulls the model out of the request.

Is this possible in the action filter? I don't have any model state validation attributes in the classes so I don't have to worry about model state is valid stuff.

Thanks